# How do I fix this "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't see the issue with my format. My schema is suppose to show the most recent date.

```
select  v.Volunteer_Name VI,
    s.Schedule_Dates SIF
from VI v, SIF s
where v.Volunteer_ID = s.Schedule_ID AND s.Schedule_ID = (select MAX(Schedule_ID from SIF));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Paranthesis` is missing in subquery in `max` function.

Add the proper `paranthesis` as following:

```
select  v.Volunteer_Name VI,
        s.Schedule_Dates SIF
from VI v, SIF s
where v.Volunteer_ID = s.Schedule_ID 
AND s.Schedule_ID = (select MAX(Schedule_ID) from SIF); 
 -- closing paranthesis added after Schedule_ID 
 -- and one closing paranthesis removed after SIF
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

One of your parentheses is simply in the wrong place. `MAX` takes a single parameter.

```
select v.Volunteer_Name VI,
       s.Schedule_Dates SIF
from VI v, SIF s
where v.Volunteer_ID = s.Schedule_ID 
      AND s.Schedule_ID = (select MAX(Schedule_ID) from SIF);
```